# Trouble getting a Blender imported mesh to be shown using Three.js

Tags: json, three.js, blender, mesh

I am trying to display a mesh, imported from blender, using Three.js.  Specifically, I am trying to display a text graphic.

I am using Three.js revision 58 and Blender 2.67.

I started by making my text object, then converting it to a mesh in Blender, since I can only find examples of loading a mesh object from Blender with Three.js.  I then exported the mesh using the Three.js .js exporter.  This is the exported mesh (fields with "..." are filled with numbers):

**test_text.json**

```
{

"metadata" :
{
    "formatVersion" : 3.1,
    "generatedBy"   : "Blender 2.66 Exporter",
    "vertices"      : 2000,
    "faces"         : 1488,
    "normals"       : 431,
    "colors"        : 0,
    "uvs"           : [],
    "materials"     : 1,
    "morphTargets"  : 0,
    "bones"         : 0
},

"scale" : 1.000000,

"materials" : [ {
    "DbgColor" : 15658734,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "Material.002",
    "blending" : "NormalBlending",
    "colorAmbient" : [1.0, 0.215860515832901, 0.0],
    "colorDiffuse" : [1.0, 0.215860515832901, 0.0],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
    "depthTest" : true,
    "depthWrite" : true,
    "shading" : "Lambert",
    "specularCoef" : 50,
    "transparency" : 1.0,
    "transparent" : false,
    "vertexColors" : false
}],

"vertices" : [ ... ],

"morphTargets" : [],

"normals" : [ ... ],

"colors" : [],

"uvs" : [],

"faces" : [ ... ],

"bones" : [],

"skinIndices" : [],

"skinWeights" : [],

"animation" : {}
```

}

I renamed the file ending from .js to .json because when I didn't I would get an error about an unexpected semi-colon in Three.js, line 204.

here is my javascipt that should load the mesh and display it:

**test_script.js**

```
var canvasHeight = $('#container').height(),
    canvasWidth = $('#container').width();

var aspect = canvasWidth / canvasHeight,
    near = 0.01,
    far = 10000;    

// get the HTML element to use as the canvas
var $container = $('#container');

// create the renderer, camera, and scene
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    view_angle,
    aspect,
    near,
    far );
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

renderer.setSize(width, height);

// attach the DOM elemect
$container.append(renderer.domElement);

scene.add(camera);   

var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

function createMesh( geometry, material ){
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(
        material ) );
  mesh.position.x = 0;
  mesh.position.y = 0;
  mesh.position.z = 0;
  mesh.scale.set( 700, 700, 700);
  mesh.overdraw = true;
  scene.add( mesh );

};

loader.load( "assets/test_text.json", createMesh );

var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);

pointLight.position.x = 10;
pointLight.position.y = 50;
pointLight.position.z = 130;

scene.add(pointLight);

camera.position.z = 300;

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

All I will see is white, instead of what I expect, which is a white background with orange 3D text saying "text".

I have not found a way to successfully point the camera in an intended direction, examples using camera.lookAt() and camera.target do not work.  however, the default camera direction will display a sphere positioned at (0,0,0), the same place as where my text should appear, so the camera direction should not be an issue.  I want to emphasize that I have been able to view a sphere set at (0,0,0), and so I do not believe this to be an issue with my general rendering and scene setup, but with something particular to the display of the mesh.

I have also tried various mesh material (eg MeshLambertMaterial, MeshBasicMaterial) to see if the material type could be an issue.

I have tried various mesh.scale settings, with and without mesh.overdraw, and I have also tried setting mesh.color so I could just see something.

It appears I am missing some key step in getting the mesh to actually be visible, but I do not know what.  I have tried changing my script to more closely match the few examples I have found online, but nothing has worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONLoader.load()` is an asynchronous call, and you are likely calling render() before the loading is complete. Add render() as the last line of your loader callback function, or add an animation loop as in the examples.

Comment: thank you very much! I've been killing myself all today trying to figure this out, and I knew it would be something simple like this.  placing the render() call at the end of the callback function made the text appear.